# How to show a UIViewController on the First time Application Launch?

Tags: iphone

I want to know how to show a page on the very first time launch of the application,I had serch for these and get many code but in my case its not working for me, I have this code in DidFinishLaunching Method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstLaunch",nil]];

    //If First Launch
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {
        //Show help view
        UIScrollView_PagingViewController *detailViewController = [[UIScrollView_PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIScrollView_PagingViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        [detailViewController release];

    }
    else {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *str =  [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:@"mybibleapp" error:&error];
    NSLog(@"previous user");

    NSLog(@"%@", str);

    if (!error && nil != str)
    {
        ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        [detailViewController release];
    }
    else
    {
        RootViewController *detailViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        [detailViewController release]; 
    }
}
```

but when i run this code ,it shows a blank white screen ,nothing shows.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstLaunch",nil]];

        //If First Launch
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {
            //Show help view
            UIScrollView_PagingViewController *detailViewController = [[UIScrollView_PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIScrollView_PagingViewController" bundle:nil];

            //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
            // ...
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

            [detailViewController release];

        }
        else {
```

i put the above code for launch UIScrollView_PagingViewController to launch .but no luck.What is the mistake i made in the above code.?.please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not placing the code in right place. Don’t put this code in AppDelegate try to keep your appdelegate as clean as possible for better @performance. Use some ViewController which will get call after splash screen and check if your code works there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push that controller at very first time but at the roo there is no any controller. so you have to add in window first. then you can push the UIViewController

```
self.window.rootViewController = detailViewController.view;
```

don't release the viewController before use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) 
    {

     UIScrollView_PagingViewController *detailViewController =[[UIScrollView_PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIScrollView_PagingViewController" bundle:nil];

                    //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
                    // ...
                    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

   self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController=self.navController;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a trcik,
Don’t put this code in AppDelegate try to keep your appdelegate as clean as possible for better performance.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**And Place this Code in you RootViewController**
Everytime when the application will get launch, it check the condition in delegate method, instead will check in RootViewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstLaunch",nil]];

    //If First Launch
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {
        //Show help view
        UIScrollView_PagingViewController *detailViewController = [[UIScrollView_PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIScrollView_PagingViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];

        [detailViewController release];

    }
    else {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *str =  [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:@"mybibleapp" error:&error];
    NSLog(@"previous user");

    NSLog(@"%@", str);

    if (!error && nil != str)
    {
        ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];

        [detailViewController release];
    }
    else
    {
       // RootViewController *detailViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] //initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

        //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

       // [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController //animated:NO];

        //[detailViewController release]; 
    }
}
```